# BufferedWriter isnt writing to file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have to take name and address of user from user and put it into textfile. I write following code:

```
package selfTest.nameAndAddress;

import com.intellij.codeInsight.template.postfix.templates.SoutPostfixTemplate;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by 
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);


        //creating addressbook text file
        File fl=new File("E:/addressbook.txt");
        fl.createNewFile();

        FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(fr);



        boolean eof=false;
        int inChar=0;

        String[] name=new String[2];
        String[] address=new String[2];

        int counter=0;


        do{
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fl);
            BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(fw);

            System.out.println("Enter "+(counter+1)+" students name "+" and address");

            name[counter]=br.readLine();
            address[counter]=br.readLine();

            out.write(name[counter]);
            System.out.println("Nmae: "+name[counter]+" ddress: "+address[counter]);
            counter++;
        }while(counter<2);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it takes input from user but the text file is empty. The address and name is not written into text file. How can I store the name and address into text file in the above code.

Comment: You need to close the stream.

Comment: I would recommend using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks for your streams, readers, writers, etc. to ensure everything is closed and flushed appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create the `BufferedWriter`, but never [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()) or [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close()) it.

These operations are what actually write to the file

---

As @ManoDestra pointed out in the comments, Java supports the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which allows you to format your statements like:

```
try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fl))) {
```

Since `BufferedWriter` implements the [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, Java will automatically take care of cleanup of `out` when the `try` block exits

Comment: @ManoDestra I never actually knew about the try-with-resources. Thanks for teaching me something new today! :)

Comment: You're welcome. A lot of good stuff in Java 7 and 8 now. I use try-with-resources a lot now and custom functional interfaces to allow me to pass lambdas that throw exceptions. Check those out too :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative to BufferedWriter is PrintStream:

```
PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(new File("filepath"));
System.setOut(printer);
```

And then you can print whatever you want to the file, e.g.

```
printer.println(name[counter]);
```

And then close it at the end:

```
printer.close();
```

Comment: I don't know if this is really a solution. OP is wondering why the file isn't getting written to, and you're proposing changing his code completely without saying why

Comment: @Jeeter Oh, sorry I'm new here. I saw your response and I just wanted to suggest an alternative for future reference.

Comment: How have I never seen `System.setOut`... Why didn't you use `System.out` after that?

Comment: @4castle You can use `System.out.print` or `printer.print` after `System.setOut`. I just redundantly put it both ways in case I forget and use `System.out` when I shouldn't be.